# I need to find which Opportunities have more than 1 Opportunity line item. How do I do this?

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

I have to find out which Opportunities have more than 1 line item. I tried doing this by making a custom report but that did not work. I was able to see which Opportunities had line items, but not how many.

I am not sure if maybe I could run some queries to get this?

Comment: Add a Roll up Summary field to Opportunity that counts the line items; then you can report on those where count > 1

Comment: welcome to SFSE, please take some time to review [ask] and take the [tour]. Restrain from asking for help and adding thanks in your posts in the future. Be sure to include what you have attempted and researched documentation/quotes to avoid having others propose already tried solutions. Thanks!

Comment: check my answer in case it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you run the following query in developer console query editor. You'll get list of all the opportunities which have opportunitylineitem.

```
select name, id, (select quantity,  pricebookentry.name, listprice, pricebookentry.unitprice from opportunitylineitems) from opportunity
```

To find out only those opportunities which have more than one opportunitylineitem. We'll need to loop on the results. And you'll need to run the following snippet in *execute anonymous apex window*.

```
List<Opportunity> opps = [select name, id, (select quantity,  pricebookentry.name, listprice, pricebookentry.unitprice from opportunitylineitems) from opportunity];
for(Opportunity o : opps) {
    if(o.opportunitylineitem.size() > 1){
        System.debug(o);
    }
}
```

I hope this will work for you. Only if you don't have as many records as the aggregate query limit says, which is 200 or 250.

> As @Derek suggested in comments. I'm making it part of my answer.

**No worries for aggregate query error now**

```
for( Opportunity opp : [select name, id, (select quantity,  pricebookentry.name, listprice, pricebookentry.unitprice from opportunitylineitems) from opportunity])
{
   List<OpportunityLineItem> oppLineItems;
   try
   {
      oppLineItems = opp.opportunitylineitem;
   }
   catch( QueryException e )
   {
      oppLineItems = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
      // Here's the 'FOR loop' the exception message says we should use
      // Within the outer SOQL for loop, this for loop can access the 
      // complete list of child oli records
      for( OpportunityLineItem oli : opp.opportunitylineitem )
      {
         oppLineItems.add( oli );
      }
   }

   // Now we can use the 'oppLineItems' List however we want. 
   System.debug( opp.name + ' : ' + oppLineItems.size() );
}
```

Comment: One thing to be aware of with this solution is that if you query an `Opportunity` with more than ~200 `OpportunityLineItems`, you're likely to run into the `Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment, use for loop` error. If you run into this error, you'll need to write an inner loop over the child records (`o.OpportunityLineItems` in this case) and store them in a temporary list, or a `Map<Id, List<OpportunityLineItem>>` to get the count.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a query to do this, but there is an easier way to do this.

You can use a [Rollup Summary field](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_defining_summary_fields.htm&type=0&language=en_US) to easily (without code, and without the testing that would be required if you were to use code) aggregate data from `OpportunityLineItem` on `Opportunity`.

The `COUNT` operation is what you're looking for here.

Comment: I created a Rollup Summary field aggregating data from line item on opportunity. i used count also. i made the filter line item greater than 1. i am still not having any luck. any idea what is wrong?

Comment: also, line item is under quote and not opportunity. is that normal?

Comment: @KateCoppola I think that filter you put in is the issue. The filter is meant to select which detail records (in a Master-Detail relationship, `Opportunity` being the 'Master' side in this case, and `OpportunityLineItem` being the 'detail') that you want to count in the rollup (and it sounds like you want to be counting _all_ of them).

Comment: @KateCoppola Also, this only counts `OpportunityLineItem` records, what you have are `QuoteLineItem` records. You can set up quote syncing and have `QuoteLineItems` automatically create `OpportunityLineItems`, but this is quickly heading into the territory where you should ask another question, or edit this question to include more details.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, efficient use of Aggregate query will be as follows:

```
SELECT OpportunityId, COUNT(Id)
FROM OpportunityLineItem
GROUP BY OpportunityId
HAVING (COUNT(Id)>1)
LIMIT 2000
```

Since, Aggregate query does not support queryMore(), take one of the following approach. Refer [Aggregate queries and Batch Apex](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000192834&type=1)

- Run the "Aggregate Query" in a schedule class by using @Read annotation.
- Implementing Iterable interface instead of Query Locator in batch class